# Testing masstransit consumer

Tags: c#, testing, masstransit

I am trying to test masstransit consumer
my consumer look like this:

```
public class FilePolicyEvaluationConsumer : IFilePolicyEvaluationConsumer
{
    public readonly IFilePolicyEvaluationCore _filePolicyEvaluationCore;
    public readonly IRepositoryClient _repositoryClient;
    public readonly IFPRepository _fPRepository;

    public FilePolicyEvaluationConsumer()
    {

    }

    public FilePolicyEvaluationConsumer(IFilePolicyEvaluationCore filePolicyEvaluationCore, IRepositoryClient repositoryClient, IFPRepository fPRepository)
    {
        _filePolicyEvaluationCore = filePolicyEvaluationCore;
        _repositoryClient = repositoryClient;
        _fPRepository = fPRepository;
    }

    public  Task Consume(ConsumeContext<InvokePolicyOnFileMessage> context)
    {
        return Task.Run( async () => {
            Guid fileId = context.Message.FileId;
            FileMetadata fileMetaData = await  _repositoryClient.GetFileMetadata(fileId);
            _filePolicyEvaluationCore.Run(fileMetaData, context.Message.CorrelationId);
        });

    }
```

but when i configure the test like this

```
_harness = new InMemoryTestHarness();
        FilePolicyEvaluationConsumer filePolicy = new FilePolicyEvaluationConsumer(); 
        _consumer = _harness.Consumer<FilePolicyEvaluationConsumer>();


        await _harness.Start();
        await _harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send(message1);
```

when i enter in the test to consumer all objects _filePolicyEvaluationCore,_repositoryClient,_fPRepository in the consumer are null, how can i inject to this objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `null` because you probably use a container in your production code and inject the constructor parameter. MassTransit has no injection built-in since it does not use any containers.

You can use the consumer factory overload to make it work:

```
_harness = new InMemoryTestHarness();
var filePolicy = new FilePolicyEvaluationConsumer(); 
_consumer = _harness.Consumer(
    () => new FilePolicyEvaluationConsumer(filePolicy));
```